# how to make a percentage calculator using python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, calculator

I want to develop a calculator that does simple math using Python with user input for one of my projects for high school, but I can't figure out how to write the input for percentage. So I was hoping that someone could assist me.

Here is my code---

```
import math

print("What kind of operation do you want to perform? ")
print("a. Add")
print("b. Subtract")
print("c. Multiply")
print("d. Divide")  
print("e. Square Root")
print("f. Percentage")
print("Please select by choosing a, b, c, d, e, or f.")

def add(ip1, ip2):
  return ip1 + ip2

def subtract(ip1, ip2):
  return ip1 - ip2

def multiply(ip1, ip2):
  return ip1 * ip2

def divide(ip1, ip2):
  return ip1 / ip2

def squareroot(ip1):
  return math.sqrt(ip1)

def percentage(ip1)
  return    

def main():
  option = (input("Choose the sort of calculation you want to perform: "))

  ip1 = int(input("Start by entering the first number you'd want to calculate: "))
  ip2 = int(input("Fill in the second number you want to calculate: "))

 
  if option == "a":
    print(ip1, "+", ip2, "=", add(ip1, ip2))

  elif option == "b":
    print(ip1, "-", ip2, "=", subtract(ip1, ip2))
  elif option == "c":

    print(ip1, "*", ip2, "=", multiply(ip1, ip2))

  elif option == "d":
    print(ip1, "/", ip2, "=", divide(ip1, ip2))

  elif option == "e":
    print(squareroot(ip1))

  else:
    print("Wrong Input")


main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you mean by input percentage.  Did you want to calculate the percentage of ip1 of ip2, or ip2 of ip1 or something else?

Comment: Observation:  You are missing the : after the function definition for percentage.  And you have not defined what the calculation will be.

Comment: Hello there, I've already made a calculator and wanted to add percentages, which I'm not sure how to do; I tried to define percentages but couldn't figure it out, so I left it blank; I was hoping you could assist me by informing me what to add and where to add it to find the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you want to calculate what percentage of the 2nd input is the 1st input. If that is the case, then you could do something like :-

```
def percentage(ip1, ip2):
  return ip1 / ip2 * 100
```

What this basically does, is that it divides the first input by the second input and multiplies the outcome by hundred. This will output what percentage the first input is of the second input.

Eg:-

`inp1 = 5,  inp2 = 10`

process: `5 / 10 * 100`

output: `50(%)`

P.S. - You also need to add the `elif` clause for `option == f`.